# "invalid conversion from [-fpermissive]" for return value of base class function

Tags: c++

I have these classes:

```
class ListItem
{
  ... some stuff ...

  public:
    ListItem *GetNext() {return somehow_the_next_item;};
};
```

```
class XYListItem : public ListItem
{
  ... some stuff ...
};
```

and this simple main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  XYListItem *xy0, *xy1;

  xy0 = new XYListItem();
  xy1 = xy0->GetNext();
}
```

Compiling this code i retrieve this error message on the line xy1 = ...:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘ListItem*’ to ‘XYListItem*’ [-fpermissive]
```

Okay, seems clear, why. ListItem is not the same as XYListItem. But how to prevent this error, without casting ListItem to XYListItem every time i call this function?

Yes, i could add a cast, but this is kind of dirty:

```
xy1 = (XYListItem*)xy0->GetNext();
```

Or i could do it like this in the derived class:

```
public:
    XYListItem *GetNext() {return (XYListItem*)ListItem::GetNext();};
```

Also kind of dirty code.

But is this the right way? I have to do this for all functions returning ListItem*.

Is there any bad missconception in my classes? I want to handle all the list stuff in the base class and all the data stuff in the derived class.

Thank you and best regards
Peter

Comment: Why do you not have `ListItem *xy0, *xy1;` in `main` ? Why do you think you need a cast?

Comment: Why close this? What kind of debugging detail is missing? Everything is clear as day.

Comment: I really don't know what to add to this question of mine. It's a minimal example, i clearly wrote about my problem and my whishes. ????

Comment: I used XYListItem and not ListItem in main, because i want to deal with the special XYListItem-data-features in main (which i did not describe, because not relevant for my problem).

Comment: Why i need a cast? A cast like xy1 = (XYListItem*)xy0->GetNext(); solves the problem. But i is kind of dirty.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your question. You can use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to handle the situation. If you declare `template <Derived> class ListItem { ... }` then functions in `ListItem` would generally accept and return `Derived*` rather than `ListItem*`. You still may need some casts in there (for example when you want to return `this`) but not as many as you would need otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution is to wrap the derived class's methods to return the right type

```
class XYListItem : public ListItem
{
  ... some stuff ...
  public:
    XYListItem *GetNext() {return dynamic_cast<XYListItem>(ListItem::GetNext());};
};
```

But in general, you need the cast, because there's no compile time guarantee that the next list item *is* a XYListItem.

If you wanted to provide that guarantee, you could use CRTP instead, which gives you a guarantee that all the `XYListItem` connected to each other are all `XYListItem` instances.

```
template<class Derived>
class ListItem
{
    //these two aren't useful for your specific case
    //but often useful in CRTP in general
    Derived* self() {return static_cast<Derived*>(this);}
    const Derived* self() const {return static_cast<Derived*>(this);}

  Derived* next;
  ... some stuff ...

  public:
    Derived *GetNext() {return next;};
};
class XYListItem : public ListItem<XYListItem>
{
  ... some stuff ...
};
```

Comment: Cool. I knew about templates, but not about this curious curiously recurring template pattern. I will try it next days ... Thank you very much!